# Remediating .NET Core App 3.1 open source dependencies vulnerabilities

Tags: c#, security, dependencies

Recently, I ran a [Whitesource Bolt](https://www.whitesourcesoftware.com/free-developer-tools/bolt/) scan on Azure DevOps targeting a .NET Core 3.1 API project.

The result is the following

[image: Screenshot of OSS vulnerability report]

For sake of accessibility, I'll report what looks relevant to this question

- CVE-2021-26701 affects `system.text.encodings.web.4.5.0.nupkg` and according to Microsoft it is advisable to `Upgrade to version System.Text.Encodings.Web - 4.5.1,4.7.2,5.0.1`
- CVE-2018-8292 affects `system.net.http.4.3.0.nupkg` and can be fixed by `Upgrade to version System.Net.Http - 4.3.4;Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Utility - 6.1.0-rc.1`

I spoke to our developer and they made a detailed analysis. These dependencies are not direct dependencies. The .NET Framework 3.1 depends on those.

They also said that the production machine is already patched with the latest version of .NET Core (no accessible version of the screenshot)

[image: .NET Installed]

The `.csproj` file indeed references `netcoreapp31` as target platform, and there is basically no additional way to force a specific version of the framework.

For sake of completeness, here is the full `.csproj file`

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <DocumentationFile>xxx.API.xml</DocumentationFile>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="8.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.15.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.NLogTarget" Version="2.15.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="3.1.9">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.1.9" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="NLog" Version="4.7.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="NLog.Web.AspNetCore" Version="4.9.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="xxx.yyy" Version="0.2.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="xxx" Version="0.8.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="5.6.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger" Version="5.6.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\xxx.Mappers\xxx.Mappers.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\xxx.Services\xxx.Services.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Properties\PublishProfiles\" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="xxx.API.xml">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>


</Project>
```

There are a couple of private dependencies, but I checked them and there is no direct dependencies to the affected packages.

Also, bulding the application shows that the affected dependencies **do not appear** in the final zip file, so they are definitely `provided` dependencies.

**Question time**

Is it really a false positive from Bolt? Can I confirm

Is it possible to commit anything to repository so that the alerts get fixed? E.g. disappear from the report?

Answer (score 2):

I have recently hit the same problem with WhiteSource - it would pick up dependencies that are not related to my projects at all - some .Net Core stuff, while I use .Net Framework.
I have studied the logs and found that `NugetDependencyResolver` somehow gets into `\.nuget\packages\` NuGet cache folder and starts picking up packages from there. Since I was running this on a build agent there were all kind of stuff there.

The resolver is part of `runPreStepCommand`. Since I run the analyzer after the build steps, I have set `nuget.runPreStep=false`.

Now it picks up only packages that do belong to my project and the run time is reduced dramatically.

Hope it is going to help someone!